# Picasso won't download valid URL

Tags: java, android, kotlin, picasso, android-glide

When I try to download an image from the website [FilmAffinity](http://filmaffinity.com) it won't work, but with other images from other websites it does. The code I'm using is

```
    Picasso.get().load("https://pics.filmaffinity.com/mamma_mia_here_we_go_again-440727588-mmed.jpg").into(imageView)
```

If I use a Callback, I see the following error: com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler$ResponseException: HTTP 403

It seems that the user doesn't have access to the website, but if I try to open that same link in Chrome, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Picasso dont support https method. You can refer the way:
The first, you can import :

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

And creating custom class :

```
    public class PicassoTrustAll {

    private static Picasso mInstance = null;

    private PicassoTrustAll(Context context) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String s, SSLSession sslSession) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                    String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates,
                    String s) throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] {};
            }
        } };
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            client.setSslSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mInstance = new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(client))
                .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("PICASSO", exception);
                    }
                }).build();

    }

    public static Picasso getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
             new PicassoTrustAll(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
}
```

You can use that:

```
PicassoTrustAll.getInstance(context)
            .load(url)
            .into(imageView);
```

I hope it can help your problem!

Comment: please note that in this way you won't check the HTTPS certificate authenticity, so you could potentially allow some kinds of attacks

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work either. It gives the same error: com.squareup.picasso.Downloader$ResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Comment: @Daniel error 403 shouldn't be linked to HTTPS, but rather to authentication/authorization. Did you try with other tools like Postman?